# Engine wouldn’t crank, replaced starter and it worked for 1 day, not cranking again.

Tags: starter, kia

My engine randomly stopped cranking with no noise at all when the key was turned. Checked battery voltages and everything looked ok. Push starting got the car going and the mechanic replaced the starter motor. The engine cranked successfully for a couple of days but stopped again. All the same signs as before. Battery voltage looks fine and push starting worked. Any ideas of what the issue could be?

Car is a Kia Cee’d.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like you may have a bad connection to the starter. I'd double check all of your heavy gauge wires going from the battery to their respective locations.